# using jQuery to swap columns in a table

Tags: jquery

What's the best way, with jQUery to swap columns in a table?

```
 <table>
      <tr>
           <td class="x"></td>
           <td class="y"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td class="x"></td>
           <td class="y"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
           <td class="x"></td>
           <td class="y"></td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

I'm using a third party plugin that generates the table and it's not very flexible, I'd like to shift the column with a class of y over as the first column and the column with a class of x as the second. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate each element with class `y` and `insertBefore` the `previous` element in your case.

```
$('.y').each(function(i,ele){
    $(ele).insertBefore($(ele).prev()) 
});
```